# AngularJS: want to display 'alias' after clicking a button

Tags: angularjs

I want to display the alias beside the age when I click a button. or when I click a name, I want the alias to be displayed besides the age of that person.

```
 <html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js">
    </script>

        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"  rel="stylesheet"></script>

    <style> 
        li {color: orange; 
            background-color: black;
            padding: 5px;
            text-align: center;

        }
    </style>

    <script>
        var myApp= angular.module("myApp",[]);
        myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope){
            $scope.residents= [       
              {fname:"Jekin", lname:"Rajal", age:29, alias:"Jek"},
              {fname:"Jaydip", lname:"Vasoya", age:24, alias:"JD"},
              {fname:"Melvin", lname:"Matthew", age:23, alias:"Anna"}]
        });
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="myCtrl" >
        <ul>
        <li type="none" ng-repeat="resident in residents">{{resident.fname}} {{resident.lname}}, {{resident.age}} </li>
        </ul>
        <br/>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="fucn"> Click to show alias</button>


    </div>
    </body> 

    </html>
```

Comment: Can't you follow the pattern and just add `{{resident.alias}}`?

Comment: if I do that, alias will be displayed without even clicking a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try wrapping the alias inside a `<div>` which is conditionally revealed after the user clicks the button:

```
<ul>
    <li type="none" ng-repeat="resident in residents">
        {{resident.fname}} {{resident.lname}}, {{resident.age}}
        <div ng-show="showAlias">{{resident.alias}}</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And then in your controller implement a handler function for the button click:

```
myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.showAlias = false;
    $scope.residents = [       
        {fname:"Jekin",  lname:"Rajal",   age:29, alias:"Jek"},
        {fname:"Jaydip", lname:"Vasoya",  age:24, alias:"JD"},
        {fname:"Melvin", lname:"Matthew", age:23, alias:"Anna"}]

    $scope.fucn = function() {
        $scope.showAlias = true;
    };
});
```

Comment: One more question.. I want to add residents to the list. I tried "$scope.residents.push($scope.addResident)". but this ain't working.

Comment: Use `$scope.residents[$scope.residents.length] = {fname:"Tim",  lname:"Biegeleisen",   age:36, alias:"Tim"}`

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks a lot for your help.